# Get model number of Mac

Tags: macos, system-profiler

I'm looking for a way to fetch the model number of a machine via any sort of script or means. I can get the serial or name, but I cannot get the model number. Not the model name, like MacPro3,1, I need the number like: 'A1315'

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455108/is-there-any-way-to-detect-a-users-mac-hardware-model-from-the-browser

Comment: @rak007 sorry, not even close

Comment: Have you tried this?
https://gist.github.com/peterblazejewicz/1825030

Comment: @Shrewd that is the serial number